# Can an Android tablet act as a speaker for an iOS device?

Tags: audio, bluetooth-audio, ios

I've seen a lot of apps that claim to use an Android device as a "wireless speaker", but they all end up needing some kind of PC client as the audio source.  I have a "smart display" that runs vanilla Android (8.0, as a tablet), and can use the Play Store.  I'd like to install something that lets me send audio directly from an iPhone.  Is this possible?  If it only works from specific iPhone apps, that would still be better than nothing.